# Determining the minimum dimension required for embedding a finite group

Tags: group-theory, geometry, finite-groups, permutations, representation-theory

Consider the groups $S_3$ and $S_4$ which are the symmetric groups on 3 and 4 elements respectively. We note that $S_3$ can be realized geometrically as the set of all rotations and reflections of a triangle. And $S_4$ similarly is the set of all rotations and reflections of a tetrahedron.

But Consider a stranger group such as $(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z})^2$ this is described as the set of rotations and reflections of a cross-like-structure that leave it unchanged. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group

So here's my question. For a given finite group $G$. How do we find the minimum euclidean dimension such that there exists a polyhedron whose set of rotations and reflections that leave it unchanged correspond to the group?

Comment: Does such a minimum exist for every group $G$?

Comment: I naviely assumed that it must be the case but your right @Servaes, i do not know this to be true

Comment: An upper bound for the minimum is the order of the group, as is very explicity proved [on mathoverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/993/is-every-finite-group-a-group-of-symmetries). See also the comments under the accepted answer there.

Comment: Do you need the group of symmetries to be $G$ exactly, or is it acceptable if it contains $G$ as a subgroup?

Comment: @Nate, it should be G exactly. If it were just a subgroup then $S_n$ for a suitably large $n$ would be a straightforward solution

Comment: As each $S_n$ corresponds to the symmetries of an (n-1)-simplex

Comment: @frogeyedpeas That still only gives an upper bound on the minimum, rather than the exact minimum.  The quaternion group embeds into $S_n$ only for $n\geq 8$, but apparently [it is the symmetries of a 4-dimensional monkey sculpture/polyhedron](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6596v1.pdf). If you embed it as a group of symmetries of some object, that should still give an upper bound of the $G$ as the full symmetry group: you should be able to just add "kinks" to the polyhedron to remove symmetries you don't want and retain the ones you do.  Though I don't know how to do that rigorously.

Answer (score 2):

Okay well partial answer: the answer should is the minimum dimension of a faithful real representation, certainly it can't be better than this.  Morally, you just choose a generic point in the space and take a convex hull of that point along with the other $|G|-1$ elements of its $G$ orbit.

Unfortunately this may have extra symmetries, take for example the action of a cyclic group of order 3 on $\mathbb{R}^2$ acting by rotations.  Any point you choose for this construction (other than the origin) will give you an equilateral triangle which has extra symmetries.

This isn't too bad though we can fix this by symmetrically truncating the polytope we get this way by hyperplanes passing through $\epsilon $-neighborhoods of our original vertices which are not perpendicular to the line from the origin to that vertex ($\epsilon$ sufficiently small so none of the truncations interact).

So now this is a purely representation theoretic question, about bounding the dimension of the smallest faithful real representation.  I'm tempted to guess $log_2(|G|)$ is the worst case attained by $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: I didnt understand "the answer should is the minimum dimension of a faithful real representation", and when you say take a convex hull of that point along with the elements in G's orbit. I don't understand how to map the elements of G to points in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Since until we have mapped the elements to points, it doesn't make sense to take a convex hull.

Comment: Okay let me unravel this a bit: A faithful representation is one which does not factor through any quotient group, in other words every non-identity element of the group acts non-trivially on the vector space.  For a non-example $S_n$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ by the sign character, but it is not faithful as half of the elements act by the identity.  This sort of action has no hope of containing the type of geometric object you are looking for as it can't distinguish between some of the group elements.

Comment: For the next part, we choose a generic point $p$ in our space, where by generic I mean it is not fixed by any element of $G$.  This is always possible whenever we have a faithful representation.  This point $p$ then defines $|G|-1$ other points, namely the points $g \cdot p$ for $g \in G$. We are taking the convex hull of these $G$ points.

Answer (score 1):

There are groups for which no such polyhedron exists, and hence there is no minimum dimension.

For example, consider a group $G$ of order $|G|=2^{\mathfrak{c}}$. If $G$ is the group of symmetries of a polyhedron in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $G$ is a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, the group of symmetries of $\Bbb{R}^n$. But $|\operatorname{Sym}(\Bbb{R}^n)|=\mathfrak{c}$, so it cannot contain $G$ as a subset, let alone a subgroup, a contradiction.

Comment: what is $c$ here? Like what is an explicit value of c for example lets pretend $c = 173$ where we groups of order$2^c$ fail to exist?

Comment: Also I did change the question to finite. I hope that doesn't affect your answer, sorry for the delay in noting that

Comment: Here $\mathfrak{c}$ denotes the [cardinality of the continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_of_the_continuum).